# How to combine (minify) compiled Angular 2 components?

Tags: javascript, angular, minify

trying to minify compiled source code of a project for production,
I'm using Gulp as the task runner.

the source files  look like this,

**html**

```
<!--... . .  various scripts and styles . . . . . --->
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <app></app>
</body>
```

my app directory structure is as follows,

```
.
├── main.js
├── main.js.map
├── main.ts
├── main.app.js
├── main.app.js.map
├── main.app.ts
├── x.component1
│   ├── x.component.one.js
│   ├── x.component.one.js.map
│   └── x.component.one.ts
└── x.component2
    ├── x.component.two.js
    ├── x.component.two.js.map
    └── x.component.two.ts
```

**app/main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {MyAwesomeApp} from './main.app'

bootstrap(MyAwesomeApp);
```

main.app.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
        <component-1></component-1>

        <component-2></component-2>
    `,
    directives: [Component1, Component2]
})


export class MyAwesomeApp {

}
```

then the components,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-1',
    template: `
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ducimus, saepe fugit illum fuga praesentium rem, similique deserunt tenetur laudantium et labore cupiditate veniam qui impedit, earum commodi quasi sequi.
    `
})


export class Component1 {

}
```

and

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component-2',
    template: `
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae ducimus, saepe fugit illum fuga praesentium rem, similique deserunt tenetur laudantium et labore cupiditate veniam qui impedit, earum commodi quasi sequi.
    `
})


export class Component2 {

}
```

All the TypeScript files are compiled down to ES5 JavaScript, further need to minified to `main.js`

so my questions are,

1. Can I run a task to collect all the compiled `.js` files to minify to a single file and reference it as `main` in production branch?
2. Does this breaks the module system import {x} from 'y'?
3. If it breaks the module loading system, what can be done to concatenate files on an Angular 2 application?

my TypeScript version is, `1.8.2`

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to compile all your TypeScript files into a single one, you need to use the `outFile` property of the TypeScript compiler. It's configurable through the gulp-typescript plugin.

This way you don't need to configure SystemJS to load module based on file names:

```
<script>
  // Not necessary anymore
  /* System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  }); */
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

The module names and their contents are now present in this single file. The same way for the packaged bundle files of the Angular2 distribution (`angular2.dev.js`, `http.dev.js`, ...). To use this file, simply include it in a `script` element.

This way you won't break module imports.

Then you can minify this single file with the uglify plugin of gulp...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work from me. If I do `System.import('app/main')` it says it cannot find the file.. If I do `System.import('app/main'.js)` it loads the file but none of the functions initiate. I most be missing something here..

Comment: Do you include the js file into a `script` element?

Comment: Yeah I have this .. `<script src="app/main.js"></script>` and then all of the scripts from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html .. under Libraries section before it. So `<script src="app/main.js"></script>` is my last one before the `System.import`

Comment: Seems minification has been added now.  https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8

Comment: I actually have this exact issue as well as described by Kris. If anyone knows how to circumvent this, please tell :).

Comment: @ThierryTemplier same thing I have done using outFile but when I uglify using gulp its not working, please can you look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501914/how-to-load-minified-file-in-angular-2-using-gulp-uglify-which-minifies-types

Answer (score 3):

** Create a single file from TS with options in tsconfig.json.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir":"client/build/",
    "outFile": "client/build/all.js",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "server"
  ],
  "include": [
        "client/*.ts",
        "client/**/*.ts",
        "client/**/**/*.ts"
  ]   
}

// Include all folders to put to a file.
```

** Build the output file and include as follows:
Example:

```
<script>


  // Alternative way is compile in all.js and use the following system config with all the modules added to the bundles.
  // the bundle at build/all.js contains these modules
System.config({
    bundles: {
      'client/build/all.js': ['boot','components/all/present','components/main/main','components/register/register','components/login/login','components/home/home','services/userdetails','services/httpprovider']
    }
  });

  // when we load 'app/app' the bundle extension interrupts the loading process
  // and ensures that boot of build/all.js is loaded first
  System.import('boot');


    </script>
```

** Minify the all.js file as you do normally.

Comment: Seems minification has been added now. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using Gulp you can just add [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) in your gulp task to combine all your JavaScript source files (as well as Angular2 sources) into one. Here's a sample of what your **webpack.config.js** could look like:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app/app',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/src', publicPath: 'src/', filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts/, loaders: ['ts-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/
    }]
  }
};
```

The relevant sections from your **gulpfile.js** are

```
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
var htmlReplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('webpack', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/app/*.ts')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/'));
});
```

Replace `gulp.dest('src/')` with the relevant location that you want your production code to reside in.

You then need to process your HTML files to have the appropriate JavaScript source file references (also in **gulpfile.js**).

```
gulp.task('html', ['templates'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(htmlReplace({
      'js': ['bundle.js']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

If you want to minify your JavaScript files you can use [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2). (Note however that there is something that goes wrong with obfuscation, hence the `mangle: false`. See this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35612100/angular2-ngif-not-working-in-deployment-environment) for more). Here's the relevant **gulpfile.js** content:

```
gulp.task('js', ['webpack'], function() {
  return gulp.src('src/bundle.js')
    .pipe(uglify({
            mangle: false
          }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

In this way your production code ends up in your `dist` folder from where you can deploy it. Now it's your choice whether you check that into a production branch or not.

Feel free to refer to my [words project on Github](https://github.com/sudoorgza/my-words) if you want to see a working version on a very small Angular2 app.

Comment: Set mangle off increased file by almost 50% for me :( there is no another solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **`@angular/cli`** you can run

```
ng build --prod
```

to minify and gzip the code.