# Angular2 TypeScript transpiler with Minification / Uglify

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, bundling-and-minification, systemjs

I'm developing a web application in **Visual Studio 2015** with **Angular2** and **TypeScript**. I'm using **Gulp** to generate distributed minified `js` files. With **Angular2** I see, that there is no need to transpile **TypeScript** neither with **Visual Studio** nor with **Gulp** as**SystemJs** does it when importing the module.

Now is the question:

How does SystemJs work with minification, uglification and so on?

```
System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

How do I minify or uglify this?

Comment: Analyzing a bit more, I see that `System.config` has a property named bundle, where I can bundle my multiple modules. I didn't find but anything about uglifying.

Comment: That options belong to [SystemJS Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder#minfication--source-maps). Angular2 tutorials don't use SystemJS Builder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SystemJS is

> Universal dynamic module loader - loads ES6 modules, AMD, CommonJS and global scripts in the browser and NodeJS. Works with both Traceur and Babel.

In fact, there are two ways to use SystemJS:

- **Transpile your TypeScript files within the browser**. This means that SystemJS loads your modules, it load corresponding TypeScript files and transpile them on the fly. The following configuration can be used in this case:

  ```
  <script>
    System.config({
      transpiler: 'typescript', 
      typescriptOptions: {
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true
      },
      packages: {
        'app': {
          defaultExtension: 'ts'
        }
      } 
    });
    System.import('app/main')
       .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  ```
- **Use previously transpiled files**. In this case, you need to use a TypeScript compiler to generate JS files from the TypeScript ones. These JS files directly rely on the SystemJS API to register and import modules.

  ```
  <script>
    System.config({
      packages: {
        'app': {
          defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
      } 
    });
    System.import('app/main')
       .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
  ```

This question could also help you:

- [Development on Angular2 with TS but without NPM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623270/development-on-angular2-with-ts-but-without-npm/35624623#35624623)

That's for the context. Regarding your question, it seems that you use the first option. To answer your question, minifying things only makes sense for the second option. As a matter of fact, this corresponds to optimize the elements to load for your applications (number of network calls, sizes of files). Since you use compiled JS files for this option you can minify / uglify them. If you want to create only one JS file, you could consider the `outFile` property of the TypeScript compiler.

See this question for more details:

- [How to combine (minify) compiled Angular 2 components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811126/how-to-combine-minify-compiled-angular-2-components/35811419#35811419)

Comment: That is brilliant. Thank you very much. As I see in the mentioned post, even the System.config is not needed anymore. YOu know why?

Comment: You're welcome! In you don't need System.config since with outFile modules are explicitly registered with `System.register` in the output file. You don't need to make the configuration the correspondance between modules and file names (what is needed without the option)...