# Angular2 - Typescript.js Files Deployment

Tags: typescript, angular

The Angular2 quickstart guide needs a typescript-1.x.x.js to be fetched but it's about 2.9MB. Even minified would still be too large. Is it best to gulp-typescript the typescript files into js files for deploying on the webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be deployed. It only has to be installed on your development environment. That's why it's in the `devDependencies` section of the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can either compile your application using the tsc command (provided by the typescript library) statically before reloading the HTML page) or on the fly within the browser using transpiling.

In the first case, you don't need to include the JS file of this library in your browser.

This question could give you more details:

- [Angular2 TypeScript transpiler with Minification / Uglify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811789/angular2-typescript-transpiler-with-minification-uglify/35814295)